# Media recorder setprofile() is not working for nexus phone

Tags: android, android-camera, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

> i have tested my code on Samsung tablet and note but same code is not
>   working on nexus.
>
> i know nexus have only front camera and camera is getting open but
>   cliking on start recording button it get crashed.... i checked it
>   through error on setProfile.
>
> MY CODE:

```
public boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Please wait..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//   mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
     mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
     int layout = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
        if (layout == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {

    switch (((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
            .getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation()) {
    case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE: {
    //  Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int degrees = 0;
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
    //      Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE 1111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    //      Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE 222-- "+ result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(result);

        break;
    }
    case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT: {
    //  Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int degrees = 270;
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        int result;
        if (CurrentValues.cur_cam_face == 1) {
        //  Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT 111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
            // System.out.println("FRONT CAMERA )))))))");

        } else { // back-facing
        //  Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT 222", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            result = degrees;// (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
            // System.out.println("BACK CAMERA )))))))");
        }

        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(result);
        break;
    }
    case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE: {
    //  Toast.makeText(context, "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int degrees = 180;
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        //  Toast.makeText(context, "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE 111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
        //  Toast.makeText(context, "ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE 22", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(result);
        break;
    }
    default: {
        //Toast.makeText(context, "DEFAULT 11", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int degrees = 90;
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        int result;
        if (CurrentValues.cur_cam_face == 1) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            result = degrees;// (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }

        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(result);
    }

        }
        }else if (layout == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
            switch (((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation()) {

            case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE: {
                Toast.makeText(context, "PORTRAIT " + ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int degrees = 0;
                android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
                int result;
                if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                    result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
                Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN_PORTRAIT 1111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else { // back-facing
                    result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN_PORTRAIT 222-- "+ result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(result);
                break;
            }
            case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT: {


                Toast.makeText(context, "else LANDSCAPE " +ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int degrees = 90;
                android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
                int result;
                if (CurrentValues.cur_cam_face == 1) {
                    result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                    result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
                } else { // back-facing
                    result = degrees;// (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
                }
                mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(result);

                break;
        }
            }

    }else
        {
            switch (((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation()) {
            case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE: {
                Toast.makeText(context, "PORTRAIT " + ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int degrees = 0;
                android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
                int result;
                if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                    result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                    result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
                Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN_PORTRAIT 1111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else { // back-facing
                    result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "SCREEN_PORTRAIT 222-- "+ result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(result);
                break;
            }
            case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT: {


                Toast.makeText(context, "else LANDSCAPE " +ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int degrees = 90;
                android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
                int result;
                if (CurrentValues.cur_cam_face == 1) {
                    result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
                    result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
                } else { // back-facing
                    result = degrees;// (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
                }
                mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(result);

                break;
        }
            }
        }

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ;
    if (CurrentValues.cur_cam_face == 1)
        camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
    else
        camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
            .toString());
    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG,
                "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: "
                        + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are trying on latest `Nexus 7`, I feel that the issue could be that `QUALITY_HIGH` is **not defined** in the `media_profiles.xml` of your device. I checked on the `AOSP` tree [here](https://android.googlesource.com/device/asus/grouper/+/android-4.2.2_r1/media_profiles.xml) and found that only `CIF`, `QCIF`, `480p` and their time-lapsed versions have been defined. You could confirm this by viewing the `media_profiles.xml` on your device at `/etc/media_profiles.xml`.

You could adapt your code to use `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P` instead of `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH`.

Comment: Interesting, this is clearly a bug in the Nexus 7, as the Android documentation of the CamcorderProfile class clearly states: "Quality levels QUALITY_LOW, QUALITY_HIGH are guaranteed to be supported, while other levels may or may not be supported. "

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple issues with your code, either of which might cause your error.

First, just creating a CameraInfo object is not enough, you must call:

```
Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
```

Without this call, you will always just get 0 for facing and orientation (default integer values).

Second, you should also be getting the profile with the method that accepts the cameraId:

```
CamcorderProfile.get(cameraId, quality);
```

I'm assuming you are properly using the Camera.open(int cameraId) method or you would probably not be getting any front-facing cameras to work.

Also, it's just convention but, I suggest you break the orientation code in the switch statements out into functions for readability.  Switch cases should ideally be just one line, but a few lines is still okay.